# Rails Capistrano deploy PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, capistrano, production-environment

```
deploy:migrating
      01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
      01 PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "customuser"
...
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

1) I can normally login to psql under customuser
2) command on server`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` is workling
3) database.yml :

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  host: localhost
  username: customuser
  password: mypassword
```

4) /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf :

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

also tried `peer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to add gem https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-postgresql

In `deploy.rb`

```
set :pg_without_sudo, false
set :pg_host, 'localhost'
set :pg_database, 'appname_production'
set :pg_username, 'username'
set :pg_ask_for_password, true
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a the same error message when attempting to deploy a Rails app with Capistrano and arrived here.

In my case, I had hardcoded a dummy password into an environment variable:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://deploy:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/myapp
```

Of course, `PASSWORD` should have been the actual password.

I'm leaving this here in case my stupidity helps someone else.